# Map of natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, natural-numbers

I'm looking at this map that maps natural numbers to sequences of natural numbers. Take a natural number $n$ and construct the unique set $A=\{k_1,k_2,k_3,...,k_m\}, k_m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n=\prod_{a \in A}^{} p_m^{a}$ (I assume no trailing zeroes to allow A to be unique). For example, n=1 maps to $\{\}$, n=2 maps to $\{1\}$, n=3 maps to $\{0,1\}$,n=4 maps to $\{2\}$ etc. This map takes care of any finitely long sequence.

It seems like it also covers all countably infinitely long sequences as well. Assume that the longest sequence is only of length k. Then that implies that there are only k distinct primes in the natural numbers, which is false. Since the length of the sequences cannot be bounded, it seems like sequences of countably infinite should be covered by this map too.

But I know this isn't right, since it shouldn't be possible to map the natural numbers into all sequences of natural numbers. What is wrong with my understanding of this map?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: It covers all *arbitrarily* large finite sequences, which is different from infinite sequences. In other words, $\omega^{<\omega}$ is countable, while $\omega^\omega$ isn't.

Comment: @Vercingetorix Could you elaborate on that a little more? What exactly is the difference between an arbitrarily large finite sequence and an infinite sequence? And how would I prove the sequence in the question fails for infinite sequences?

Comment: If $n$ maps to an infinite set then that means $n$ has infinitely many divisors, which of course is not possible. As for your first question, I said abitrarily large sequence*S*. $\omega^{<\omega}$ consists of sequences of length $k$ for *any* k. But that doesn't mean it contains infinitely long sequences. $\omega^\omega$ on the other hand contains infinitely long sequences. The former is countable while the latter isn't.

Comment: It's like, consider $\{1, 11, 111, 1111,...\}$. This containns sequences (of 1s) of arbitrarily large finite length but there's no infinitely large sequence of 1s in it.

Comment: @Vercingetorix "It's like, consider {1,11,111,1111,...}. This contains sequences (of 1s) of arbitrarily large finite length but there's no infinitely large sequence of 1s in it."--Is this because an infinitely long sequence of 1s would not be a natural number? How would you formalize the idea that while the sequences of 1s has unbounded growth on its length, infinitly large sequences are still impossible? Intuitively it feels like since the cardinality of {1,11,....} is $\mathbb{N}$ then the 'last' item in the list has length $|\mathbb{N}|$ How would I rigorously see that as wrong?

Comment: Well I don't think you *should* be able to "rigorously" show that such things are impossible because they *can* actually be formalized via the notion of ordinal numbers. When we're restricting ourselves to natural numbers however, those aren't a problem. This follows basically by definition as natural numbers being collections of strictly finite stuff. So an infinitely long sequence of 1s wouldn't be a natural number almost by definition of $\mathbb{N}$ as containing the strictly finite (ordinal) numbers.

Comment: @Vercingetorix For natural numbers, its true by definition that the nth natural number has a cardinallity $n$, and therefore that a set with cardinality $n$ is a set of natural numbers from $1$ to $n$. So, if a set of natural numbers exist with length $|\mathbb{N}|$, it seems like there should be a corresponding set that goes from $1$ to $|\mathbb{N}|$, with the largest number being $|\mathbb{N}|$. How do you count all the way up to $|\mathbb{N}|$ without ever using $|\mathbb{N}|$? It seems like if $|\mathbb{N}|$ isn't a part of N, then N can only have up to $|\mathbb{N}|-1$ different numbers

Comment: Also, I appreciate your help--I apolgize that I'm sometimes a slow learner! Some of the intuition for infinite numbers is very counter-intuitive

Comment: The difference between an arbitrarily large finite sequence and an infinite sequence is that an arbitrarily large finite sequence is a finite sequence, whereas an infinite sequence is an infinite sequence.

Comment: You're not supposed to *have* an intuition for the infinite. You're supposed to *develop* an intuition for the infinite by putting aside all the intuitions you've accumulated for the finite, while studying a rigorous development of the properties of the infinite.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Before, I had been thinking that a sequence is finite if it is bounded. In other words, prove that there exists some bound, and that proves it finite. I had interpreted something as infinite if assuming it has a bound implies a larger bound exists. But this fails: for example, no bound exists for natural numbers yet each natural number is finite. How do you prove then that something is infinite then?

Comment: A set is infinite if and only if it can be put in one-to-one correspondence with a proper subset.

Comment: Everything OK now, Caleb?